# Props are undefined/empty object in async function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have a stateless functional component that gets data from redux and uses that send a mutation to graphQL. I'm also using lodash's `get` and `getOr` for prop selection. The problem is that in my `submit` function below, I'm trying to use `props` to pass form data in to the request/mutation. Unfortunately when I `console.log` props on the outside of the `async` function, `formData` is populated with the information i need. When I use `props` inside of the async function, nothing is to be found. Is there something I'm doing wrong here? Example below:

```
const BeforeRequestModal = (props) => {
  console.log(props.formData) // formData shows redux data here
  const submit = async () => {
    console.log(props.formData) // formData is an empty object here?
    try {
      console.log(props.formData) // formData is an empty object here as well?
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }

  return (
    <Modal size="sm">
      copy copy copy
      <ConsentForm />
      <Button
        text="Request"
        onClick={submit}
      />
    </Modal>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  formData: getOr({}, 'member-consent.data', state.form),
})

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps)
)(BeforeRequestModal)
```

Comment: Nothing seems to be off here. What is the `Button` class. You might have to check its behaviour of handing the `submit`.